# pg_upgrade and tablespaces (postgres 9.2 to 9.3)

Tags: migration, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3, upgrade

I have a 9.2 installed with tablespaces sitting at:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main
```

and

```
/opt/postgres/9.2/second
```

And unfortunately they are on different filesystems.

This is a Debian package installation of 9.2. The 9.3 will be compiled from source. Since every example I have seen does not show how to deal with a second and a third table space, does anyone have the correct command line for this?  Does `pg_upgrade` take multiple `-d` and `-D` options?

The intent is for the data to stay on the same file systems and to use link-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL creates subdirectories named for the PostgreSQL version within each tablespace.

So AFAIK `pg_upgrade` doesn't need to be told to take special action for the tablespaces. It will use the same tablespaces as the original database, but won't conflict because of the use of different subdirectories within the tablespace root.

The caveat is that if you have tablespaces inside your 9.2 data directory, this won't work. You shouldn't do that in the first place. Move the tablespaces to a location outside the 9.2 datadir before doing the upgrade.